# Copying data into separate worksheet from userform input with specific ranges

Tags: excel, vba, userform, transfer

I'm having 2 issues with the following code. The code works fine to do what it has to do; that being that it takes user input from a userform and transports the data into a worksheet called "Sheet1" and inputs data on the next row after each time activates the userform via a command button. But my first issue is that I want the data to stop at row 32 without the If statement at the bottom of the code. A simpler way would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lngWriteRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Archive")
lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
If lngWriteRow < 3 Then
lngWriteRow = 3
 End If
ws.Range("A" & lngWriteRow) = txtday.Value
ws.Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = txthour.Value
ws.Range("C" & lngWriteRow) = teamcomboBox1.Value
ws.Range("E" & lngWriteRow) = resourceComboBox1.Value
ws.Range("F" & lngWriteRow) = batchComboBox1.Value
ws.Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = machinecomboBox1.Value
ws.Range("H" & lngWriteRow) = quantitycomboBox1.Value
ws.Range("I" & lngWriteRow) = "3000" & txtsu.Value
' Paste data in Archive sheet
  ??Missing Code??
If lngWriteRow > 31 Then
MsgBox "Reached final entry. Please save file and upload to sharepoint."
ws.Range("A" & lngWriteRow) = ""
ws.Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = ""
ws.Range("D" & lngWriteRow) = ""
ws.Range("E" & lngWriteRow) = ""
ws.Range("F" & lngWriteRow) = ""
ws.Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = ""
ws.Range("H" & lngWriteRow) = ""
ws.Range("I" & lngWriteRow) = ""
End If
End Sub
```

My second issue actually draws from my first issue. I want to save the data onto a separate worksheet called "Archive", but the code only lets the user input data up to row 32, which poses a problem for the second block of code below that I had tried. It does copy the data into the second sheet, but once the first sheet gets filled with data, it is erased via separate command button and the data just gets overwritten in the second worksheet once the user uses the userform again.

```
ws2.Range("A" & lngWriteRow) = txtday.Value
ws2.Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = txthour.Value
ws2.Range("C" & lngWriteRow) = teamcomboBox1.Value
ws2.Range("E" & lngWriteRow) = resourceComboBox1.Value
ws2.Range("F" & lngWriteRow) = batchComboBox1.Value
ws2.Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = machinecomboBox1.Value
ws2.Range("H" & lngWriteRow) = quantitycomboBox1.Value
ws2.Range("I" & lngWriteRow) = "3000" & txtsu.Value
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Indenting the code blocks would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

1. I can't think of anything simpler than a simple `If` statement to stop data processing after row 32.
2. You are trying to do two separate functions but your question implies that you use the same method to do both. You want to identify a new variable to replace `lngWriteRow` (based on the last row of your Archive, not Sheet 1) so that you do not overwrite the data in the archive, a value that can be assigned a value greater than 32.